# Embeddings and Characteristic Property of Subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Any embedding obeys the char. prop. of subspaces: "If $X_0\cong A\leq X$ then $X_0\hookrightarrow X$"
Does the converse hold as well: "If $X_0\hookrightarrow X$ then $X_0\cong \mathrm{im}\leq X$"

...where '$\cong$' means 'being homeomorphic'
...where '$\leq$' means 'being subspace'
...where '$\hookrightarrow$' means 'obeying characteristic property'
...where '$\mathrm{im}$' means 'image of'

Comment: By char. prop. you mean $f:Y\to X$ is continuous iff $if$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, by '$X_0\hookrightarrow X$' i mean '$f:Z\to X_0\text{ continuous}\iff \iota\circ f:Z\to X\text{ continuous}$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a funciton $\iota:(X_0,\tau_0)\to(X,τ)$ with the universal property that for a space $(Y,\sigma)$ a set map $f:Y\to X_0$ is continuous iff $ι\circ f$ is continuous. Then first of all $ι=ι\circ\text{Id}$ is continuous since $\text{Id}$ is.
Now let $A=\text{Im}(X_0)$ be the subspace of $(X,τ)$ with $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ being the inclusion satisfying(?) the universal property. This means the restriction $\barι:X_0\to A$ is continuous iff $ι=i\barι$ is continuous, which is true. Conversely, $\barι^{-1}$ is continuous iff $i=ι\barι^{-1}$ is, which is true as well.

Comment: What if $\iota$ is not injective? (e.g. $\iota:[0,1]\to[0,1):\iota(x\neq 1):=x, \iota(1):=0$)